How to Process CSV Data in Hourly Batches of 2000 Users Using MuleSoft?
I'm working on a project where I need to process a CSV file containing user data in hourly batches using MuleSoft. Each batch should consist of 2000 users, and the processing needs to be continuous such that each new batch starts from where the previous batch ended. Specifically, the first batch should process users 1 to 2000, the second batch should process users 2001 to 4000, and so on.
Requirements:
Read the CSV file.
Implement batch processing for 2000 users per hour.
Ensure each subsequent batch starts from where the last one ended.
Automate the batch processing every hour.
Maintain state to track the last processed index.
Could someone guide me on how to implement this in MuleSoft? Any sample flows, connectors, or tips would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
As I tried batch processing but unable to update last processed csv index in mule

The question is not clear and requires more focus and details. What did you try? Share the code in the question. Why it didn't work? Are there errors? Questions in [so] should be specific. Asking for generic samples is not an specific issue. See [ask].

Do you have to read from same CSV file always? Or the new data comes in different CSV? Will your CSV always have 2000 records to read? can't it be less then it?

I have a CSV file containing 10,000 user records, and I want to read this data in chunks of 2000 records per hour. For instance, in the first hour, I need to read records 1 to 2000, in the second hour, I need to read records 2001 to 4000, and so on until all records are read.(on hourly basis)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@HarshankBansal Do you have any idea / suggestions for above explained use case.

@user25736894 Maybe I can help but it is not clear which part do you need help with. Is it the processing of the data? or is it getting the data the file after your last processed line? And how are you reading the file?
